# How to set realm for Basic Authentication Scheme in .Net HTTPListener Google Chrome issue

Tags: .net, http, authentication, google-chrome, httplistener

I'm working with an HttpListener.  I can set the Authentication mode to basic using: listener.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

This works in IE, but Google Chrome doesn't seem to like empty realms.  So the header should contain something like: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="The Byte that Overflew the Stack"

However, I can't find a place to set the realm value and HttpListener does not allow you to directly access the WWW-Authenticate header key.

Is there a way around this?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under my nose the whole time:

listener.Realm = "Overflow";